# Getting LyX to Find and Use OpenType Fonts

Tags: lyx

I have a family of opentype fonts which I want to use directly in LyX? I know that the TeTeX and LuaTeX backends to LyX can use opentype fonts directly. How can I get LyX to see the fonts and use them?

Comment: I hope you don't have TeTeX as your distribution. There has been no new release since 2006. I don't know LyX, but a general answeris that you must ask to compile either with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, and load the `fontspec` package, make declarations like `\setmainfont{name_of_the_font}`. You can use (for text) any font known to your system. See the fontspec documentation for details.

Comment: please always put what you have tried so far but didn't work. Have you tried going to Document > Settings > Fonts and putting "Use non-TeX fonts" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernard. Your response to my question has enabled me to discover the power of the fontspec package. I am making progress with exploration of the capabilities of the package. I am very grateful for the answer.

Comment: Thanks scottkosty. Setting preferences as suggested by your answer has made it possible for me to use non-TeX fonts in LyX.

Answer (score 1):

To use non-TeX fonts in LyX, go to Document > Settings > Fonts and check "Use non-TeX fonts".